# モバイルフレンドリー対応で、「コンテンツの幅が画面の幅を超えています」とSerch Consoleでエラーが出てしまいます。

Tags: css

モバイルフレンドリー対応したいのですが、「コンテンツの幅が画面の幅を超えています」とSerch Consoleでエラーが出てしまいます。
今考える原因としては、画像スライダーと、ハンバーガーメニューの二つでメニュー一覧は

```
right: -25rem;
```

にして表示させないようにしています。

この2つの場合がやはり、原因なのでしょうか？
その場合はいかにして対応していく方法がありますか？

初心者です、すみません。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 実際にそのエラーが発生するときの URL (またはソースコード) を追記していただけませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

表示させないということは画面外に飛ばすのではなくCSSで表現する場合は

```
display:none;
```

を設定するか。
コンテンツのエリアはそのまま表示されなくしたいということであれば

```
visibility:hidden
```

を利用しましょう。